# Create thumbnail in php

Tags: php, thumbnails, crop

I am trying to find a script which can create thubnail by cropping and transforming. For example: the original image size is 800x750. But I want to create a thumbnail of size 150x110. So it should first transform the image to that size and then crop the area which falls out. Hope I made myself clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Timthumb is a good resource used by a lot of Wordpress styles.  Here is the link: http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `timthumb` plugin.

```
http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/
```

Comment: I beat you by 22 seconds ;-)

Comment: @vinsanity38 thats not a matter. Only care about its helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

there is two main methods to create proportional thumbnail:

1. "touch from inside" - for this method you will need to downscale your image to NOT exceed your size (150, 100), so you will get image which size for one side is the same and the other side is `less or equal` (examples: 140x100, 150x90), then you will need to `fill` space around this image to fit exactly 150x100
2. "touch outside" - for this method you will need to downscale your image that one side is the same, another side is `greater or equal` (examples: 160x100, 150x110), in this case you then need to `crop` to fit

select any method you want, math for both methods are elementary